# Breeze How to write entity related queries against local cache

Tags: breeze

I am trying to figure out how to write a query that will filter my related entities using the executeQueryLocally.

Here is my example:

```
   var queryStageConfigs = breeze.EntityQuery
       .from("Stages")
       .where("StageConfig.ConfigValue", '==', 'Green')
       .expand("StageConfig");

   var stageConfigs = self.manager.executeQueryLocally(queryStageConfigs);
```

This the error I am getting back:

Error: unable to locate property: ConfigValue on entityType: Stages:#

MetadataStore

```
    //Stages Entity
    metadataStore.addEntityType({
        shortName: "Stages",
        //namespace: "MonitoringCenter",
        dataProperties: {
            id:             { dataType: DT.Int64, isPartOfKey: true },
            institutionId:  { dataType: DT.Int64 },
            qualifiedName:  { dataType: DT.String },
            displayName:    { dataType: DT.String },
            displayOrder:   { dataType: DT.Int64 },
        },
        navigationProperties: {
            institution: {
                entityTypeName: "Stages",
                isScalar: true,
                associationName: "Institution_Stages",
                foreignKeyNames: ["institutionId"]
            },
            stageConfig: {
                entityTypeName: "StageConfig",
                isScalar: false,
                associationName: "Stages_StageConfig"
            }
        }
    });
    metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName("Stages", "Stages");

    //StageConfig Entity
    metadataStore.addEntityType({
        shortName: "StageConfig",
        //namespace: "MonitoringCenter",
        dataProperties: {
            id:             { dataType: DT.Int64, isPartOfKey: true },
            stageId:        { dataType: DT.Int64 },
            configName:     { dataType: DT.String },
            configValue:    { dataType: DT.String },
        },
        navigationProperties: {
            stages: {
                entityTypeName: "StageConfig",
                isScalar: true,
                associationName: "Stages_StageConfig",
                foreignKeyNames: ["stageId"]
            }
        }
    });
    metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName("StageConfig", "StageConfig");
```

I am hand writing the JsonResultsAdpater to get the JSON data into the entities that have created using the metadataStore setting up the relationship between the entities.

When I query the Stages entities I can see the StageConfigs array and it is not empty.

Any clue on what I may be doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your example is a little confusing because I can't tell the cardinality of the relationships based on your names.  In general, I think of a pluralized name like 'stages' as being a collection of 'Stage' entities (i.e. isScalar = false). But in your case the 'stages' property is actually scalar and its inverse, the 'stageConfig' property, a singularized name, is actually non-scalar.  If this assumption is correct then the reason that your query will not work is because the stage.stageConfig property needs to be a scalar in order for your query to work, unless you want to use the 'any/all' operators. i.e. something like

```
var queryStageConfigs = breeze.EntityQuery
   .from("Stages")
   .where("StageConfig", "any", "ConfigValue",  "==", 'Green');
   .expand("StageConfig");
```

(  and shouldn't the query be called 'queryStages' because you are querying and returning 'stages')

Also, just a nit, but its probably a good idea to keep all of your entityType names singular and your resource names plural. This is not a requirement, but it is certainly confusing the way you have one entityType singularized ( StageConfig) and another pluralized (Stages).

I don't see any mention in your code about using the camelCase naming convention, but the example seems to indicate that you are assuming that this is set.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. I will try to clarify.

Comment: I have an 2 entities, 1 called Stages that should be related to StageConfig based the id in the stages entity and stageId in the StageConfig entity. This seems to be correct becuase when I look at the objects in the Javascript I get an array of StageConfig under the Stages object.

Comment: what I am really asking is how to write an entity query that is based on the entities relationship. As I am trying above. Please keep in mind that I trying to query just local entities using the executeQueryLocally!

Comment: Side note - I also tried the following in the Pluralsight Code Camper but getting the same problem:

Comment: function getSpeakersLocal() {
            var query = EntityQuery
                .from("Person")
                .where("speakerSessions.speakerId", '==', 15);
            var speakers = manager.executeQueryLocally(query);
            return speakers;
            //var orderBy = 'firstName, lastName';
            //var predicate = Predicate.create('isSpeaker', '==', true);
            //return _getAllLocal(entityNames.speaker, orderBy, predicate);
        }